# Screaming darkness

Tags: meaning

What does "screaming darkness" mean? The context is as follows:

> Now the wind was rushing past him, carrying with it loose pieces of
> clothing, sheets of paper, food from the kitchen, anything that had
> not been fixed in place. He had a moment to see this, then the lights
> went out and he was in screaming darkness.

I can't find it anywhere.

---

[Edit to provide provenance and context]

User amdn found this passage on [a Russian website](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:F-GXCSn5xjMJ:www.english-school.narod.ru/Space_odysey_6.rtf+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) where it appears to be a loose translation of Arthur C Clarke's [*2001: A Space Odyssey*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=HtDpW3qwc88C&pg=PT120&lpg=PT120&dq=screaming+darkness+%22a+space+odyssey%22&source=bl&ots=8suryS2ct7&sig=XFQhSouUDkyBw9dyM6IpNgHxv_k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6d4iVaLtFo7fOPrYgPgM&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=screaming%20darkness%20%22a%20space%20odyssey%22&f=false):

> In the steeply curving corridor of the centrifuge, the wind was howling past, carrying with it loose articles of clothing, pieces of paper, items of food from the galley, plates and cups — everything that had not been securely fastened down. Bowman had time for one glimpse of the racing chaos when the main lights flickered and died, and he was surrounded by screaming darkness.

The context is provided by earlier text at the start of Chapter 28.

> A moment later all other sounds were submerged by a screaming roar like the voice of an approaching tornado. Bowman could fee the first winds tugging at his body; within a second, he found it hard to stay on his feet.
>
> The atmosphere was rushing out of the ship, geysering into the vacuum of space. Something must have happened to the fool-proof safety devices of the airlock; it was supposed to be impossible for *both* doors to be opened at the same time. Well, the impossible had happened.

Comment: The wind is screaming. The night is dark. So *screaming darkness*.

Comment: That's a quote from "2001: A Space Odyssey," scientist Dr. David Bowman has forced entry into the spaceship after the computer refuses his command to "Open the pod bay doors, HAL!" Air is escaping into space and Bowman has seconds of consciousness left but he makes it into an emergency pressure chamber.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gpwvJzcfL1w

Comment: Assuming what amdn says is correct, the phrase is not in any way a familiar idiom, but still has a sort of metaphorical meaning.  Bowman would have experienced total chaos, followed by utter silence, until air returned to the airlock.  Even if the lights didn't actually go out he would have quickly lost his eyesight from the pressure change and the effect of the moisture on his eyeballs boiling away.  If he had tried to scream he would not have been able to, as there was no air, giving a certain metaphorical meaning to "screaming darkness".

Comment: Archived in Google cache, don't know how long this link will last http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:F-GXCSn5xjMJ:www.english-school.narod.ru/Space_odysey_6.rtf+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Answer (score 1):

It's simply a combination of "screaming" (an approximate synonym of "howling") - implying the sound made by a very strong wind, and "darkness" - what you get when the lights go out.  The two have been combined into one phrase for literary effect.

This provides a contrast to the stillness and/or quiet that is more commonly encountered when it is dark.

Answer (score 0):

Ever heard the expression "Pitch black"? Expressions like these are a way for the author to let you feel the world that she is creating. "Screaming darkness" is just to let you feel the eeriness of the location.

Comment: Seems more like it's evoking terror rather than just eeriness.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that **screaming darkness** doesn't have a specific meaning. The deal here is the word **screaming**, which is there to express that it is very dark.

For instance: If I say this sun is screaming bright I mean that the sun is very bright and may burn my skin hard.

Take this **screaming** as **very**

Answer (score -1):

"Screaming darkness" is a literary device called oxymoron where two things that exclude each others are combined. The effect here should be to highten the idea of darkness. Sometimes such oxymora have a certain effect, sometimes they sound very artificial  and are no more than a cheap literary trick.

There are a lot of similar terms such as paradoxon and others and it can be quite difficult or sometimes impossible to distinguish one literary term from the others.

Comment: I wouldn't call `screaming darkness` an oxymoron. It's a verb the noun cannot do but not contradictory like `brilliant darkness`.